# php find a menu item with class name and insert markup

Tags: php, regex, wordpress

I have a wordpress menu created with one menu item that has the class 'wishlist'. Using the wordpress **'wp_nav_menu_items'** filter I can get the entire markup for all the menu items, in one long string:

```
public function wishlist_count( $items, $args ) {
    var_dump($items);
    return  $items;
}
```

I am looking for the best approach using php, to first find only the menu item with the class **'wishlist'** and then insert some custom markup into that menu item. Then add the updated markup back to $items string before returning it.

Here's what the $items string outputs:

```
<li id="menu-item-10" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-10">
    <a href="http://localhost/powell/shop/">Shop</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li id="menu-item-14" class="wishlist menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-14">
            <a href="http://localhost/powell/wishlist/">Wishlist</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: So what does the $item look like?

Comment: Why would you use php in such case? It seems that JavaScript is the best tool to achieve this without any problems.

Comment: jQuery will definitely get this done...But I am still interested in how I can achieve this in PHP. Seems I have all the data/information I need within that Wordpress hook. With using jQuery I would have to setup localized vars for js, because there is more to the code, like getting the 'logged in user id' and 'user wishlist count' which would have to be passed to JS. Granted not a huge issue but curious if PHP can help me get this done.

Answer (score 1):

So..Unless I totally misunderstood the question,  a lot is going on ( wrong ) in this question and comments .

First - you do not need to write a special function to see `$items` , wordpress has this one already in the form of [`wp_get_nav_menu_items()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_nav_menu_items)

Then, you have a special filter exactly for css classes in menus called `nav_menu_css_class`

usage would be along the lines of

```
function my_special_nav_class( $classes, $item ) {

    if ( is_single() && $item->title == 'Blog' ) {
        $classes[] = 'special-class';
    }

    return $classes;

}
```

then apply the filter

```
add_filter( 'nav_menu_css_class', 'my_special_nav_class', 10, 2 );
```

That being said , you can also do that via UI ..

In `Appearance > Menus`, click the `Screen Options` tab

Under `Show advanced menu properties`, check CSS Classes.

Now expand any menu item to reveal the CSS Classes (optional) text input.

Now, if you want to inject a more complicated markup

```
    add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items','some_added_function', 10, 2);

    function some_added_function( $nav, $args ) {
        if( $args->theme_location == 'primary' )// target the menu
// add markup
            return $nav."<li class='menu-header-search'><form action='http://example.com/' id='searchform' method='get'><input type='text' name='s' id='s' placeholder='Search'></form></li>";

        return $nav;
    }
```

That of course would depend on your markup because if you only need to change some link attributes there is another filter `nav_menu_link_attributes`

```
add_filter( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', function( $atts, $item )
{
    if( isset( $item->classes ) )
    {
        $atts['class'] = join( 
            ' ', 
            array_filter(
                $item->classes, 
                function( $val )
                {
                    return 'li-class-' !== substr( $val, 0, strlen( 'li-class-' ) );
                } 
            ) 
        );
    }
    return $atts;
}, 10, 2 );
```

All that assuming you want to do that in `php` like you wrote in Original question,and not dynamically - on-the-fly - client side . so not really need `js` or `jQuery` - Again, assuming I did not misread your question.

Comment: Think you need to reread the question. I said I already have the menu item created with a class of 'wishlist'. However the 'wp_get_nav_menu_items()' function you mentioned might be very useful. Be nice to have the items separated into an array opposed to a long string.

Comment: @George So what didn´t i understood ? is there something you need to do that can not be done with any of the filters I have mentioned ? Inserting markup is in the examples ..

Comment: Well like I mentioned above you missed the first part of the question. Secondly I don't need to add a class or markup to the entire menu. Third, I am not trying to update the link attribute. What I need to do is find a specific menu item with the class of 'wishlist' and add markup to it. And like I mentioned the 'wp_get_nav_menu_items()' function, that you mentioned, should do the trick, thanks for that. Because I can run a loop on each menu item check first if has the class 'wishlist' then I know to add my special markup to only that link.

Comment: well, in my opinion the `wp_nav_menu_items` will do what you need . Of course, it need to be adjusted to your needs , which I did not do ( just an example how to target a single menu item ).